# Laravel Passport: use api guard for passport specific routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm writing a REST API using laravel (5.6) and passport. In the documentation it says that it's possible to use the json api for making passport specific requests (for example to get tokens, create or edit clients etc).
(https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#managing-clients)

However when I want to use these passport routes in my angular frontend using the REST interface, y get "Unauthenticated" errors, also while using the correct access token.

I searched the passport classes (mainly `RouteRegistrar`) and found that they always use the web guard.
How to solve this?

I searched if it's possible to configure the Passport::routes() in some way but did not find anything in the docs. So is the only solution not using the `Passport::routes();` and writing custom routes with `auth:api` middleware instead of `auth:web`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found something:

In the AuthServiceProvider under boot, put

```
Passport::routes(null,array('middleware'=> 'auth:api'));
```

instead of only

```
 Passport::routes()
```

This merges the middleware as options. I leave it here in case someone else runs into this issue.

Comment: you just want change the passport middleware from web to api?

Comment: @LeandroRR
yes that was the plan. The above solution works for the moment, but it seems I run later on into missing CSRF Token errors (since it's api and the auth:web still exists in the RouteRegistrar class). Either I will make exceptions for the passport routes in VerifyCsrfToken, or replacing them completely by custom routes...

Comment: i removed csrf token